# Changing MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters for SimpleMembershipProvider in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider, simplemembership

I have a simple mvc4 application which uses OOTB SimpleMembership. Now I want to change MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters for it. How can I do it? Do I need to change web.config file and add a membership element which is type of SimpleMembershipProvider?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to modify your web.config file, and modify the value of `minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters` according to your needs.

consider the following snippet as an example:

```
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
           type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, 
           Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
           connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
           enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
           enablePasswordReset="true" 
           requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
           requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
           maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
           minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
      ==>  minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
           passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
           applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

you can learn more about SImple membership from this amazing article: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Comment: ok, but you have set the type of Membership provider to be DefaultMembershipProvider. does it means that it uses SimpleMembershipProvider? or I have to change it to SimpleMembershipProvider?

and I gout this error.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

Comment: you must include in the references of your project the library: System.Web.Providers.dll.
Rightclick your desired project=> click on "references", then point out to the mentioned DLL and everything should be working fine.

Comment: I added the assembly by using Nuget. Now when it wants to create users it generates this error:

To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".

Comment: yes I know, this issue is addressed in the link at the end of my answer, have you checked it out?

Comment: quoted from the mentioned link: _You'll get the following execption in AccountController.cs::Register: To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider". This occurs because the ASP.NET Universal Providers packages include a web.config transform that will update your web.config to add the Universal Provider configuration_.
pleae check the article as it provides very useful information regarding SImple membership provider and ways to get it working. Hope i could help you.

Comment: Yes Mohammed, I have checked the article and read it several times. I gave up, I will use simplemembership without configuring password settings. thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry for the end result, wish you the best of luck.